# If statement bug in VHDL

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, fpga, hdl, modelsim

I am facing a problem in VHDL via ModelSim. It is an error in my if statement.

```
if ((s(0) = c(0)) AND (NOT(x1(0)))) THEN 
   I:= (others => '0');
 end if;
```

Here is my if statement and the error is:  No feasible entries for infix operator "and".
But, after I tried to check the program I realized that the problem is with using (not gate). Maybe, there is another way of using it in vhdl.
Could anyone help??
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have no indication of the type of `x1`.  It's telling you the expression `NOT(x1())))` isn't compatible with any defined AND operator visible by selection (e.g. context clause specified package visibility).

Try evaluating `x1(0)` to a value instead of simply using the inversion operator.

for example:

```
if s(0) = c(0) AND x1(0) = '0' THEN 
    I:= (others => '0');
 end if;
```

Should `x1` be a type whose element type can be specified with the enumeration value '0'.

(There's a precedence order to operators that says all your parentheses were redundant).

Comment: If `x1` is a `std_logic_vector`, then `x1(0)` is a `std_logic`, as is `not x1(0)`, whereby the `and` operator goes `{boolean} and {std_logic}`, but there is no definition of `and` for this combination of types, which is what ModelSim tries to tell with the message 'No feasible entries for infix operator "and"'.  Applying Davids example will make the second argument to `and` a `boolean`, which will work, since `and` is defined for two `boolean` arguments.

Comment: More specifically the relational operator for equality ("=") outputs a binary result whose type is BOOLEAN.   The logical operator NOT will produce a value compatible with the type of (in the case) `x1`.  There is no AND defined that will take a BOOLEAN left argument and an element type as a right argument. There's an extensive section in the IEEE Std 1076 on expressions, with a subsection on operators.

Comment: I strongly agree with your thoughts, but what should I do with such situation?

Comment: @user3300910: As both David and Morten are saying - use `x1(0) = '0'` rather than `not x1(0)`